# Finding intersections between a large number of sets with unique elements each

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory, set-intersection, neighbours

The following is an interesting algorithmic problem.

**Inputs:**

- The set of elements `S` (say, non-negative integers).
- A mapping `N` that maps some elements from `S` to a subset `S_k \subset S`. (not all elements of S are represented, neither in keys nor in values). Each `S_k` consists of unique, sorted elements only.

*Example inputs:*

```py
S = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
N = {
   0: [1, 2, 3],
   4: [2, 3, 5, 6],
   6: [5, 7, 8],
}
```

Let us denote by `N[s]` the set of elements corresponding to `s` (e.g., in the example above, `N[0] = [1, 2, 3]`).

**The goal**

Build a mapping `M` that maps keys in `N` to subsets of keys in `N`. The mapping should be of the form `s_j: S_j` where `s_j \in S, S_j \subset S`, and any `s` is included in the `S_j` if `N[s_j]` and `N[s]` have common elements.

*Example result:*

```py
{
   0: [4],
   4: [0, 6],
   6: [4],
}
```

The parameters are as follows:

- length of `N` ~100K elements
- is the number of elements in the correspondence (`|N[s]|`) ~10
- the number of unique elements (`|S|`) ~100K

The following is my attempt at solving the task. It starts with building an inverted index, then iterating it to construct the result. Should be `O(|N|)` complexity but I'm unsure.

```py
def merge_sets(sets: Sequence[Set]) -> Set:
    """List of sets in, a single merged set out. """
    if not sets:
        return set()
    return reduce(or_, sets)


def neighbors_to_mutexes(
        indexes: Union[List[int], np.ndarray],
        neighbors_by_index: Union[List[List[int]], np.ndarray],
) -> Mapping[int, Set[int]]:
    """Given a list of indexes and a list of respective neighbors for each index,
    find indexes whose neighbor lists share at least one element."""

    inclusion_by_index = defaultdict(set)  # which sets of neighbours is each index included in
    neighbors_by_index = [set(neighbors) for neighbors in neighbors_by_index]
    global_indexes = merge_sets(neighbors_by_index)
    for index in global_indexes:
        inclusion_by_index[index] = {
            other_index
            for other_index, neighbors in zip(indexes, neighbors_by_index)
            if index in neighbors
        }

    intersecting = defaultdict(set)
    for index, including_set in inclusion_by_index.items():
        for i, j in product(including_set, including_set):
            if i != j:
                intersecting[i].add(j)
                intersecting[j].add(i)

    return intersecting
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a graph problem with a bipartite graph, where each value in the lists is an intermadiate node on the way to other keys in N.

```
graph = {k: set(v) for k,v in N.items()}
for k, vals in N.items():
    for val in vals:
        graph.setdefault(val, set()).add(k)
 
result = {}
for k in N:
    for val in graph[k]:
        for k2 in graph[val]:
            if k2 in N and k != k2:
                result.setdefault(k, set()).add(k2)
 
result
# {0: {0, 4}, 4: {0, 4, 6}, 6: {4, 6}}
```